# How to defeat framework injections?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, code-injection, ld-preload

Is anyone hardening their code in an attempt to detect injections? For example, if someone is trying to intercept a username/password via NSUrlConnection, they could use `LD_PRELOAD/DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, provide exports for my calls into NSUrlConnection, and then forward the calls to the real NSUrlConnection.

Ali gave excellent information below, but I'm trying to determine what measures should be take for a hostile environment, where a phone might be jail broken. Most applications don't have to care, but one class of apps do - high integrity software.

If you are hardening, what method(s) are you using? Is there a standard way to detect injections on Macs and iPhones? How are you defeating framework injections?

Comment: You could apply a number of run-time protections.  I have worked on apps where we applied linker flags to stop [unexpected] dylibs being loaded, we stopped app repacking (to stop people adding malicious libraries), we loaded anti-debug detections, we checked that system library calls were not being hooked & we blocked the latest reverse engineering tool libraries.  But what is the point if you don't have equally strong `at-rest` or `in-transit` controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS / CocoaTouch, loading dynamic libraries is not allowed* (except for the System frameworks). To build and distribute an Application thru the AppStore, you can only link with static libraries and system frameworks, no dynamic library.

So on iOS you can't use that for code injection, neither can you use `LD_PRELOAD` of course (as you don't have access to such environment variables on iOS).

*Except for jailbroken iPhones probably, but people jailbreaking their iPhone should take upon themselves that jailbreaking is by definition lifting all securities provided by iOS to avoid things such as injections (so you can't expect to remove the lock on your door to avoid having to use your key… and still expect that you're still protected against thieves robbing your house ;-))*

That's the advantage of the Sandboxing + CodeSigning + No dylib constraints on iOS. No Code injection possible.

(On OSX it is still possible anyway, inparticular using LD_PRELOAD)

---

[EDIT] Since iOS8, iOS also allows dynamic frameworks. But as that's still sandboxed (you can only load code-signed frameworks that are inside your application bundles, and can't load frameworks that comes from outside your app bundle) injection is still not possible*

**except if the user jailbreaks its phone but it means that s/he chose to get rid of all protections and purpose and thus put its phone at risk — we can't crack our phone security and still expect it to provide all the protections those securities provided*

Comment: Thanks Ali. I should have been more specific. I'm looking at a Jailbroken device (and I've seen the injection library - I have the sources). So the idea is to harden the executable in a hostile environment.

Comment: @uchuugaka yes but only frameworks embedded in your bundle, and those are then only loadable from binaries located inside your bundle (namely: your app and your app "extensions"), so this is still bundled in the app sandbox and injection still can't happen. The only way to do dynamic injections would be to have the code to inject in a framework that you embed in the app bundle yourself, but it won't be able to load third-party frameworks located outside your bundle, only frameworks you included when your built and signed your app.

Comment: Read up on `frida.re`.  Also, nothing stops you re-signing an app bundle and re-installing. Granted, it will have lost the app store encryption, but who cares?  Check out `node-applesign`.

Comment: hi @AliSoftware can you please also provide the source of the info, it would be a great help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer specific to UNIX like operating systems, I apologize if it doesn't make sense for your question but I don't know your platform well. Simply don't create a dynamically linked executable.

There are two ways I can think of to do this. Method #2 is probably best for you. They're both similar.

**Important** for both, the executable **must** be statically compiled using `-static` at build time

1. Method 1 - static exe, manual load shared libraries by their trusted full paths

Manually `dlopen` each library you need via a full path and then get the function addresses via `dlsym` at runtime and assign them to function pointers to use them. You'll need to do this for every external function you want to use. I believe reentrant unsafe functions won't like this so for those that use static variables- you'll need to use the reentrant safe versions, these end with "_r"  i.e. use `strtok_r` instead of `strtok`

This will be difficult or simple depending on what your app does and how many functions you're using.

2. Method 2 - Statically link the executable, period

You can solve your subversion problem by just linking a static executable to avoid using dynamic libraries at all. This will generate a much larger exe than the the `dlopen()/dlsym()` method. Build using the `-static` compile flag and instead of using, for example `gcc bah.c -o bah lssl` use `gcc -static bah.c -o bah /usr/lib/libssl.a` to use the statically compiled version of the libraries you need instead of the dynamic shared libraries. In other words, use `-static` and don't use `-l` while building

For either method:

1. Once built, use `file bah` to confirm the executable is statically linked. Or confirm by running `ldd` on it
2. Note you'll need statically compiled versions of all the libraries you're linking against present in your system. These files end with`.a` instead of `.so`)
3. Also note upgrading system libraries will not update your executable. If there's a new security bug in OpenSSL, you'll need to get the latest libssl.a and recompile it. If you use the `dlopen()/dlsym()` method you won't have this problem but you will have portability issues if symbols change in different versions

Each method has its pros and cons based on your needs.

Taking the method 1 `dlopen` and `dlsym` approach makes your code more "obfuscated" and smaller, but sacrifices portability in most cases so probably isn't what you want. The upside is that it can possibly benefit when security bugs are fixed system wide.